# Display List of Class in C++

Tags: c++, list, class, displayobject

Hello i'm new in programming and i'm trying to display a list of class in C++
i tried this :

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
class Person
{
public:
    std::string Name;
    Person();
    virtual ~Person();
}

#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Person p;
list<Person> lp;
p.Name= "Smith";
lp.push_back(p);
while (it != lp.end())
{
    cout << *it;
    it++;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

but it display nothing, i don't know why ! can someone help me please ? thank you

Comment: Wouldn't you want to print out `Person::Name`?

Comment: Do you really think this has anything to do with the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the `Person::Name` field you would have to change your print statement

```
cout << *it;
```

to

```
cout << it->Name;
```

which will print out the name field in the `Person` instance.

Alternatively, you could overload `operator <<` for you class, as described in @JerryCoffin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `cout << *it;` part is just fine.

What you've neglected to do is overload `operator<<` for your class. To assure consistency I'd probably change it to require a name when you create a Person, and then make `Name` a private member so outside code can't mess it up:

```
class Person
{
    std::string Name;
public:
    Person(std::string Name) : Name(Name) {}
    virtual ~Person();

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Person const &p) { 
        return os << p.Name;
    }
}
```

Then your code to create and print out a list could look something like this:

```
std::list<Person> people { "Smith", "Jones" };

for ( auto const &p : people)
    std::cout << p << "\n";
```